# How to make guide lines based on near by widget while dragging the widget like fabric canvas

Tags: flutter, dart

when I dragging the widget I wants to make guide lines based on near by widget like fabric canvas.
[image]

Comment: You will need to keep track of the LTRB coordinates of the other widget in the canvas. There are a number of ways to do this that entirely depend on your approach.